# Express - get router.get to return json data attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am new to javascript and would like to retrieve the json response from my express route get request. I can return the whole json but when i try to return a specific element i recieve an error (eg **res.body.data).** Here is my route file

route.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  request({
    uri: 'https://www.reddit.com/r/meme/new/.json'
  }).pipe(res);
});
module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require("cors");
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var testAPIRouter = require('./routes/testAPI');
var route = require('./routes/route');

var app = express();
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/testAPI', testAPIRouter);
app.use('/route', route);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: should be req.body.data req.query will get you the querystrings

Comment: i am trying to save data attributes returned from the response when i hit this link with a http get request : https://www.reddit.com/r/meme/new/.json

Answer (score 1):

You need to use body parser:

```
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: app.js added above